# Convert a string to a property name

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class named `AnchorLoadclass` with properties like `diameter`, `thickness`. I have got a list of *properties* in a list. Now I want to iterate through a list and *set value* of properties as:

```
myanchor.(mylist[0]) = "200";
```

But it's not working.
My code is as:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnchorLoadclass myanchor = new AnchorLoadclass();
        var mylist = typeof(AnchorLoadclass).GetProperties().ToList();
        myanchor.GetType().GetProperty(((mylist[0].Name).ToString())) = "200";

        myanchor.thickness ="0.0";
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myanchor;         
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you forgot to mention in the question, the line

```
myanchor.GetType().GetProperty(((mylist[0].Name).ToString())) = "200";
```

*doesn't compile* (please avoid *doesn't working*). You have to do this:

```
 // 1. Get property itself:
 String name = "diameter"; // or mylist[0].Name or whatever name

 var propInfo = myanchor.GetType().GetProperty(name);

 // 2. Then assign the value
 propInfo.SetValue(myanchor, 200);
```

Often, it is a good practice to

```
  // Test, if property exists
  if (propInfo != null) ...

  // Test, if property can be written
  if (propInfo.CanWrite) ...
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PropertyInfo to set the property value (200) on the object (myanchor) as follows:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = myanchor.GetType().GetProperty(((mylist[0].Name).ToString()));
propertyInfo.SetValue(myanchor, 200);
```